# How to print some references of the main bibliography again?

Tags: bibtex

I have to write my PhD annual activity report. In a section, I am talking about my research citing many references (including some of my publications) that appear in the bibliography section at the end of the document.
However, I also have to list all my publications in a separate section. How can I print only my publications in that section?

My main.tex file looks something like this:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}

\begin{document}

\section{Research}
Some text citing my work \cite{mywork2019} and others' work \cite{otherswork}.

\section{My Publications}
\printmypublications    % Some function that prints only my publications

\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
\bibliography{bibliography}

\end{document}
```

My bibliography.bib file looks like this

```
@inproceedings{mywork2019,
  title={My Work},
  author={Me},
  booktitle={Conference},
  year={2019}
}

@inproceedings{otherswork,
  title={Others' work},
  author={Someone else},
  booktitle = {Some Conference},
  year = {2019}
}
```

Is there a function that prints some specific references?

Answer (score 0):

I think it only prints references after you have cited them (that's the case with biblatex). If you want to print references you have not cited, you may have to define a new command(s) yourself. However, if you want to print different references in different bibliographies you just make separate .bib files and print them. Alternatively, you could use biblatex and write this in the end:

```
\printbibliography[type=article,title={Articles only}]
\printbibliography[type=book,title={Books only}]

\printbibliography[keyword={physics},title={Physics-related only}]
\printbibliography[keyword={latex},title={\LaTeX-related only}]
```

and something like this in the start:

```
\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=authortitle,
sorting=ynt
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{ bibliography.bib}
```

You can read more about this at overleaf's help pages:
https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Natbib_bibliography_styles
https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Biblatex_bibliography_styles
https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Bibliography_management_in_LaTeX

Answer (score 0):

I will share my experience with Biblatex, as I was trying to do something very similar to you in my thesis.

I have to reference many different types of documents, and my university requires that they be separated into different lists of references. To achieve that, I created one .bib file for each type of reference (e.g. scientific literature, legislation, and case law).

Using Biblatex, I used the following code:

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa,language=english]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}
\addbibresource{norms.bib}
\addbibresource{cases.bib}
```

And in my .bib files, I tag the references with keywords:

```
@legislation{DelBene_2021,
keywords    =   {norm},
location    =   {H.R.1816, 117th Congress (2021-2022)},
title       =   {Information Transparency \& Personal Data Control Act},
url         =   {https://www.congress.gov/bill/117th-congress/house-bill/1816?s=3&r=5039},
author      =   {DelBene, Suzan K.},
year        =   {2021},
month       =   {03}
}
```

Then, when I call the bibliography, I filter each list by the keywords:

```
\printbibliography[title={References},notkeyword=norm,notkeyword=law]
\printbibliography[title={Referenced Norms},keyword=norm]
\printbibliography[title={Referenced Case Law},keyword=law]
```

This creates 3 different lists of references, including in each one only the references containing the specific keyword.

You could try using a keyword for general references and another for your own work.

Anyway, this will print only the references you have cited.

Comment: Can you please add an compilable tex code for a fast proof ....

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't have a compilable tex code available for a fast proof, as all code is from my thesis, that I'm still writing and so I can't share entirely. And it's divided into multiple .tex files, that I edit and include separately. I would need to edit all documents to remove sensitive information, and then share it as a .zip file so it could be adequately compiled.